# Extracting coefficients in matrix form from VARMAX statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

Is there any way to call the VARMAX model results (intercept, AR and MA) from statsmodels in matrix array format **without** either manually inputting it or writing a procedure with series of loops?

```
model = VARMAX(endog=df_data[['stock','bond']],order=(1,1))
results = mode.fit()
print(results.params)
```

I get

```
intercept.stock        0.011664
intercept.bond         0.002932
L1.stock.stock         0.120046
L1.bond.stock         -0.978197
L1.stock.bond         -0.010727
L1.bond.bond           0.360093
L1.e(stock).stock     -0.012520
L1.e(bond).stock       0.000342
L1.e(stock).bond       0.001340
L1.e(bond).bond       -0.013166
sqrt.var.stock         0.089868
sqrt.cov.stock.bond   -0.001321
sqrt.var.bond          0.008202
```

I'd like the arrays in this format (or similar):

```
In[1]: arr_intercept
Out[1]: array([[0.011664],
               [0.002932]])
In[2]:arr_AR
Out[2]: array([[ 0.120046, -0.978197],
               [-0.010727,  0.360093]])
In[3]:arr_MA
Out[3]: array([[-0.01252  ,  0.000342 ],
               [ 0.0013407, -0.013166 ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing my script for extracting intercept, AR, MA results in matrix format. If p>1 or q>1 then the resulting AR and MA coefficient matrices will be 3-dimensional

```
# parameters to run statsmodels.varmax
depvar = ['stock', 'bond', 'gold']
nvar = len(depvar)  # number of dependent variables
p = 2
q = 2
model = VARMAX(endog=df_data[depvar], order=(p, q))
results = model.fit(maxiter=1000, disp=False)

# intercept matrix results
arr_intercept = np.zeros(nvar)
for i in range(0, nvar):
    arr_intercept[i] = results.params['intercept.' + depvar[i]]

# AR lagged coefficients matrix
mat_coef_ar = np.zeros((p, nvar, nvar))
for i in range(0, p):  # axis=0 loop for lags
    for k in range(0, nvar):  # axis=1 loop for columns
        for j in range(0, nvar):  # axis=2 loop for rows
            coefa[i, j, k] = results.params['L' + str(i + 1) + '.' + depvar[k] + '.' + depvar[j]]

# creating MA epsilon coefficient matrix
mat_coef_ma = np.zeros((q, nvar, nvar))
for i in range(0, q):
    for k in range(0, nvar):
        for j in range(0, nvar):
            coefu[i, j, k] = results.params['L' + str(i + 1) + '.e(' + depvar[k] + ').' + depvar[j]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following attributes of the `results` object:

```
arr_AR = results.coefficient_matrices_var
arr_MA = results.coefficient_matrices_vma
arr_intercept = results.conf_int(alpha=1).iloc[:2,:1].to_numpy()
```